# getImageData convert to toDataURL HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

is there a way to convert image data from getImageData to toDataURL in HTML5?

```
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(x - (lineWidth/2), y - (lineWidth/2), lineWidth, lineWidth);
```

x and y is position of the mouse pointer on the canvas, I am creating drawing app to get image data from existing canvas and put it (copy) in new canvas. from that image data i want to create pattern with `createPattern`. any idea? please help me

Answer (score 3):

You don't need getImageData to copy a portion of canvas1 onto canvas2.

(getImageData is slow)

Just create a temporary canvas and drawImage part of canvas1 to the temporary canvas.

Then use the temporary canvas to create a pattern for use on canvas2.

```
var pattern=ctx2.createPattern(patternCanvas,'repeat');
```

It's even simpler if all of canvas1 will be used as the pattern.  Then just do this:

```
var pattern=ctx2.createPattern(canvas1,'repeat');
```

Example code and a  Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/rKxn3/

```
var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");
var patternCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var patternCtx=patternCanvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";
function start(){

    ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);

    patternCanvas.width=80;
    patternCanvas.height=47;
    patternCtx.drawImage(canvas1,0,0,80,47,0,0,80,47);

    var pattern=ctx2.createPattern(patternCanvas,'repeat');
    ctx2.fillStyle=pattern;
    ctx2.fillRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);

}
```